# Neural network weights update without target

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to create a feed forward neural network for learning to play poker. I have a lot of data for games of poker (several hundred thousand hands).

The snag is that in a game of poker there is no target value for what winnings, it's good to get above 0 profit but that's not a target. There is possibly the target profit of betting all your chips and winning the maximum amount but almost all hands will have wins/losses which are distant from this so I want to avoid that.

In the past I have only come across weights updating techniques which use the deviation from a target value. Is there some method I can use where a profit above 0 encourages that decision and a profit below 0 discourages the decision?

Comment: can you give an example of your poker-hands data?

Comment: I would disagree with your statement that there is no target value for what is winning poker. There absolutely is values within poker that will over several thousands of hands indicate a winning strategy. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your point but there are values you can extract from hand histories that indicate a winning strategy. Analyse your hand history and you'll notice optimal strategy such as playing in position, aggressive play, selective hand range based on position(wider late, tighter early), etc, etc. Don't necessarily worry about the end result, focus on what is good winning play.

Comment: You've tagged your question with "reinforcement-learning". So I think you already know the answer...

Comment: @vathek sorry for my flow reply, I posted this while I was on lunch at work and didn't get back to it until now. From the data on a group's play I pick one player and from that game determine the data for poker hands includes the raises and calls everyone has made so far this round of betting and previous rounds of betting. I calculate the probability of my hand beating a random hand. There are numerous other miscellaneous variables like the size of the pot. I discretized all these variables so that, for example, the probability of beating a random hand is either 0-20%, 21-40%, ..., 81- 100%.

Comment: @rcpinto The reinforcement learning methods I found were not suitable. They were all for situations where I can replay the poker hands again and again with it making different decisions. But I cannot, each hand can only be played once and the decision for what to bet is already assigned in the data set.

Comment: The bet is the action. So you're saying you're trying to learn to make the same bets? If that's the case, you're not learning to win, but to copy other players' style.

Comment: Oh that's not what I meant. What I mean is that it would be told decision X, Y, Z were made and they resulted in this profit. Quite like telling the program "You made these decisions and it resulted in this profit" so it learns that those decisions were good or bad and adjusts weights accordingly. Do you know of a type of learning algorithm which can do this?